# Update Default Root Object of Cloud front Distribution in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a simple C# windows forms app. What I am trying to accomplish is modify the Default Root Object of one of my Cloud front Distributions. I can't seem to find any related articles that describes how this is accomplished. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of trial and error Here's the C# code to update an AWS cloud front distribution. You will need AWS's new modularized assemblies. AWSSKD.Core v3 & AWSSDK.Cloudfront.

First you need to get the current Distribution for 2 reasons. Mostly for validation you'll need to grab the Etag and Caller Reference. Etag to var and Caller Reference to string.

```
    var client2 = new AmazonCloudFrontClient();
            var tag = client2.GetDistributionConfig(new GetDistributionConfigRequest
            {
                Id = "YOURDISTID"
            }).ETag;

            string cf = client2.GetDistributionConfig(new GetDistributionConfigRequest
            {
                Id = "YOURDISTID"
            }).DistributionConfig.CallerReference;
            client2.Dispose();
```

Next you will need to make a update to the distribution. What I have below is the minimally required to update a distribution (Pretty much Everything you see in the AWS console when editing a distribution.

Take notice of where tag variable and cf string are used. If the Etag's do not match you will get 400 bad request back.

```
    var client = new AmazonCloudFrontClient();        
            client.UpdateDistribution(new UpdateDistributionRequest
            {
                Id = "YOURDISTID",
                DistributionConfig = new DistributionConfig
                {
                    WebACLId = "",
                    HttpVersion = "http2",
                    IsIPV6Enabled = true,
                    DefaultRootObject = "maintenance.html",
                    CacheBehaviors = new CacheBehaviors {
                        Quantity = 0,                            
                    },
                    Restrictions = new Restrictions {
                        GeoRestriction = new GeoRestriction
                        {
                            Quantity = 0,
                            RestrictionType = "none"
                        }
                    },
                    CustomErrorResponses = new CustomErrorResponses {
                        Quantity = 0                            
                    },                     
                    ViewerCertificate = new ViewerCertificate {
                        SSLSupportMethod = "sni-only",
                        ACMCertificateArn = "YOUR_IMPORTED_CERT_ARN",
                        MinimumProtocolVersion = "TLSv1.1_2016"                           
                    },
                    Enabled = true,
                    Comment = "Maintenance",
                    Origins = new Origins
                    {
                        Items = new List<Origin>() {
                            new Origin(){Id = "S3-example.example.com", DomainName = "example.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com", S3OriginConfig = new S3OriginConfig(){ OriginAccessIdentity = "" }, OriginPath = "", CustomHeaders = new CustomHeaders{ Quantity = 0 } }
                        },
                        Quantity = 1                           
                    },
                    Logging = new Amazon.CloudFront.Model.LoggingConfig
                    {
                        Bucket = "example.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com",
                        IncludeCookies = false,
                        Enabled = false,
                        Prefix = ""
                    },
                    PriceClass = "PriceClass_All",
                    Aliases = new Aliases
                    {                         
                        Quantity = 1,
                        Items = list
                    },
                    CallerReference = cf,
                    DefaultCacheBehavior = new DefaultCacheBehavior
                    {
                       ForwardedValues = new ForwardedValues
                       {
                           QueryString = false,
                           QueryStringCacheKeys = new QueryStringCacheKeys {
                               Quantity = 0
                           },
                           Headers = new Headers {
                               Quantity = 0                                  
                           },
                           Cookies = new CookiePreference
                           {
                               Forward = "none"                                   
                           }
                       },
                       AllowedMethods = new AllowedMethods {
                           Quantity = 2,
                           Items = httpmeth,
                           CachedMethods = new CachedMethods
                           {
                               Quantity = 2,
                               Items = httpmeth
                           }
                       },
                       DefaultTTL = 86400,
                       Compress = false,
                       MaxTTL = 31536000,
                       TargetOriginId = "S3-example.example.com",
                        LambdaFunctionAssociations = new LambdaFunctionAssociations {
                           Quantity = 0
                       },                          
                       ViewerProtocolPolicy = "allow-all", 
                       MinTTL = 0,
                       SmoothStreaming = false,
                       TrustedSigners = new TrustedSigners
                       {
                           Enabled = false,
                           Quantity = 0,                                                            
                       },               
                    }
                },
                IfMatch = tag
            });
            client.Dispose();
```

If you have issues with ACMCertificationARN not being found in the reference Assembly chances are you are using the old v2 AWSSDK.  Remove\Uninstall it. Get the latest Nuget Package for [AWSSKD.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Core/)   & [AWSSDK.CloudFront](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.CloudFront/)

Nuget Package Manager Console Install:

```
    Install-Package AWSSDK.Core -Version 3.3.21.17
    Install-Package AWSSDK.CloudFront -Version 3.3.6.3
```